# Can you use libgit2 to clone a git repository?

Tags: git, libgit2

Is there a way to create a new clone of a git repo using libgit2? From the libgit2 usage guide (http://libgit2.github.com/api.html), various examples docs (http://schacon.github.com/libgit2-examples/  etc.) and the "repository" libgit2 api docs (http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/group__git__repository.html) and other reading... I only see references to either opening an existing git repo dir, `git_repository_open`, or creating a new one, `git_repository_init`.

Is there something obvious I am missing? Perhaps the api equivalent of "git clone GIT-REPO-URL" is `git_repository_init` followed by ... ?

Comment: Would you consider to accept the newer answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not yet implemented in libgit2. None of the network protocols are yet implemented in libgit2 as far as I know. libgit2 is still a work in progress; it is useful for inspecting an manipulating a local repository, but not for doing network operations yet. For now, if you want to do network operations like cloning (or even local cloning), you are going to need to just shell out to the regular `git` executable.

Comment: There is now basic support for cloning and bare cloning.

Answer (score 26):

Libgit2 is *indeed* a work in progress... but it looks like things are moving fast :)

It is now possible to fetch from a remote repository. You can find some pointers to code samples in **[this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8553578/335418)**.

### Update

The clone feature has just been **[merged](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/778)** into the libgit2 repository.

- **[clone.h](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/eb87800ab631d19a7655f01ece130455b1cc976a/include/git2/clone.h)** header
- sample code usage in **[examples/network/clone.c](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/eb87800ab631d19a7655f01ece130455b1cc976a/examples/network/clone.c)**

Answer (score 6):

I've contributed this feature to the python binding of libgit2 ;)

Now you can clone in python as well.

```
repo_path = "git://github.com/libgit2/pygit2.git"
path = "/tmp/pygit2"
repo = clone_repository(repo_path, path)
```

Hope it helps!