# How to clone/fetch a git repository with libgit2?

Tags: git, libgit2

I need to initialize a git repository and fetch the latest version of a branch into it. In bash, the commands are:

```
git init
git remote add -t $BRANCH -f origin $REMOTE
```

I'm trying to do the same programmatically with libgit2, but am having trouble finding the equivalent for the second line. The calls to create a remote are apparent, but I'm not seeing any to add it to a repository or handle the branch.

Is it possible to do this with libgit2? If not, is there a library capable of doing this?

Comment: I don't know about using libgit2, but isn't doing a `git clone <url>` much simpler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

High level steps describing how to implement a fetching process in libgit2 can be found **[here](http://librelist.com/browser//libgit2/2011/12/3/libgit2-questions/#180df46d1cfd0705f85af728ad44403e)**.

You can find example of codes performing such task **[here](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/examples/network/fetch.c)** and **[here](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/501)**. Beware these examples might get a little out of sync as the API is moving on.

Please note that those pieces of code will retrieve all newer commits (*a branch is only a pointer to a specific commit*) from the upstream defined remote.

As of today, there's no way to perform a checkout in libgit2 yet.

Provided you need some more help, I'd recommend those two places:

- the libgit2 mailing list (via libgit2@librelist.com)
- the libgit2 [issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues)

### Update

The clone feature has just been **[merged](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/778)** into the libgit2 repository.

- **[clone.h](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/eb87800ab631d19a7655f01ece130455b1cc976a/include/git2/clone.h)** header
- sample code usage in **[examples/network/clone.c](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/eb87800ab631d19a7655f01ece130455b1cc976a/examples/network/clone.c)**

As part of the pull request, the author took care of providing the users with a checkout implementation as well.

- **[checkout.h](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/eb87800ab631d19a7655f01ece130455b1cc976a/include/git2/checkout.h)** header
- checkout related **[unit tests](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/eb87800ab631d19a7655f01ece130455b1cc976a/tests-clar/checkout/checkout.c)**

Comment: This answers the question, although it's a shame libgit2 isn't functional enough to handle this.